# Items randomly appears in RecyclerView

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have made a simple app for taking notes, it works fine. When i scrolled up or down the screen, they are randomly expanded or shows previous screen states when scrolled as seen here [screen1](https://ibb.co/C0k93Mv) (no scrolling) and [screen2](https://ibb.co/jvq3nvf) (when scrolled)
Any help is very much appreciated.

My adapter code is below:

```
class NoteListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteListAdapter.ViewHolder>(), {
    private var wordList: List<EnEntity> = arrayListOf()
    private var filteredWordList: List<EnEntity> = arrayListOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.note_list,
            parent, false
        )
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(word: EnEntity) {
            itemView.zk_entitle.text = word.titleWord
            itemView.zk_custword.text = word.customWord

            itemView.note_list_main.setOnClickListener {
                val action = EnFragmentDirections.actionEnFragmentToNoteFragment(word)
                itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
            }

            //the eye icon
            itemView.zk_eye.setOnClickListener {
                if (itemView.zk_custword.isGone) {
                    itemView.zk_custword.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    itemView.zk_eye.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
                } else {
                    itemView.zk_custword.visibility = View.GONE
                    itemView.zk_eye.clearColorFilter()
                }
            }
            if (word.isFavorite) {
                itemView.zk_faved.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else{
                View.GONE
            }
            
          /**  show heart icon*/
            itemView.zk_faved.setOnClickListener {
                if (itemView.zk_faved_deson.isGone) {
                    itemView.zk_faved_deson.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
            itemView.zk_faved.setOnLongClickListener {
                val t = Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 60)
                t.show()
                true
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //search
        holder.bind(filteredWordList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = filteredWordList.size

    fun setAllWords(wordItems: List<EnEntity>) {
        this.wordList = wordItems
        this.filteredWordList = wordItems
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying setHasStableIds(true) to your adapter
like so:

```
class NoteListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteListAdapter.ViewHolder>(), { 
init {
    setHasStableIds(true)
}
```

Then add the following two functions inside your adapter class

```
  override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }
```